# Kafka Size of ISR Set(3) insufficient for min.isr 2

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I have a strange Kafka Server error when mirroring data with the MirrorMaker 1 in Apache Kafka 2.6.

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotEnoughReplicasException: The size of the current ISR Set(3) is insufficient to satisfy the min.isr requirement of 2 for partition FooBar-0
```

The strange thing is, that the `min.isr` setting is 2 and the ISR Set has 3 nodes.
Nevertheless I get the *NotEnoughReplicasException* Exception.

Also taking a deeper look to the topic does not show any curiosities

```
[root@LoremIpsum kafka]# /usr/lib/kafka/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --topic FooBar
Topic: FooBar       PartitionCount: 1       ReplicationFactor: 3    Configs: min.insync.replicas=2,cleanup.policy=compact,segment.bytes=1073741824,max.message.bytes=5242880,min.compaction.lag.ms=604800000,message.timestamp.type=LogAppendTime,unclean.leader.election.enable=false
        Topic: FooBar       Partition: 0    Leader: 3       Replicas: 2,3,1 Isr: 3
```

The logs of the 3 nodes look normal (as far as I can judge). Is there any other reason that could produce this message. What else could be checked?

Thank you very much for any advice!

---

**ConsumerConfig**

```
exclude.internal.topics=true
auto.offset.reset=earliest
enable.auto.commit=false
isolation.level=read_committed
partition.assignment.strategy=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor
max.partition.fetch.bytes=5242880
```

**Producer config**

```
acks=all
enable.idempotence=true
max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=1
#retries=
#delivery.timeout.ms=
#request.timeout.ms=
#linger.ms
batch.size=1000
max.request.size=5242880
```

Comment: I think "ISR Set(3)" in the error message means that only broker #3 is in sync. This is also visible in the  kafka-topics output. Therefore the error message makes sense. I guess something is going wrong with the synchronisation/replication between broker. Can you also show producer properties of mirror maker 1?

Comment: Thanks mike. Than I misunderstood the infos. Unfortunately I have to quit at the moment and I'll get back to you later. Didn't expect such a quick reaction. ;-)

Comment: Okay, sure. I just left an answer below as I am not sure when I'll be back ;-)

Comment: If you're using Kafka 2.6, why not MirrorMaker2?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Started with MirrorMaker 1 - no need to switch yet. Would it make anything better here?

Comment: It would copy topic configs for you, I believe. Also syncs offsets, in case of cluster failover, if thats something you're interested in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "ISR Set(3)" means that only broker #3 is *in-sync*. This is also visible in the output of the kafka-topics command. Apparently, there is something going wrong with the replication of the data between the brokers.

Under the covers of MirrorMaker1 there is a plain KafkaConsumer and KafkaProducer which do the work. According to the JavaDocs of the Producer [Callback](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Callback.html) the `NotEnoughReplicasException` is a **retriable** exception.

Therefore, you are likely to get rid of this error by setting the following producer configurations:

```
acks=all: The number of acknowledgments the producer requires the leader to have received before considering a request complete. This controls the durability of records that are sent. 
retry.backoff.ms=1000: The amount of time to wait before attempting to retry a failed request to a given topic partition. This avoids repeatedly sending requests in a tight loop under some failure scenarios.
delivery.timeout.ms=300000: An upper bound on the time to report success or failure after a call to send() returns. This limits the total time that a record will be delayed prior to sending, the time to await acknowledgement from the broker (if expected), and the time allowed for retriable send failures.
```

All details on the KafkaProducer configurations are given [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html).

Comment: Thanks. I added the configuration to my question. The configuration was done in taking the confluent white paper "Optimizing Your Apache Kafka Deployment" with regard to "durability" into account. The `delivery.timeout.ms` is also mentioned here also but I thought 120.000 (default) should be enough. In my Use Case a record should not really take longer to mirror (rather much less).
But I will have a try and come back.

Comment: I also found out that there seems to be a hidden MirrorMaker producer config `producer.type` ([here](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.6/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/MirrorMaker.scala#L526-L527)). Maybe running `sends` in sync mode will result in faster acknowledges but I guess it will press performance down. There are some things to try...

Comment: +1 mike as you clarified the error message for me; for now I think my problem is, that the cluster nodes maybe are not really connected together and therefore fail replicating the records. I try to verify this now.